# How to show number of outcomes per filter applied? [advanced filtering]

Tags: filter, data

I'm working on an advanced filter for a data platform containing many thousands of rows.

My filter is split in to categories, which then have various options for the user to select.

I'm looking to be able to show the number of outcomes still remaining in the table, based on each individual filter category which has been applied as shown in the image.

The platform i'm designing is used to answer highly specific questions, and a based on the type of data we're working with, a single filter could be the difference between 4 or 40 results, and I'm attempting to make it clear using this 'funnel' approach.

Are there standards for this type of approach? Does this have a name?[image]

Comment: We spent some time live on YouTube this week to work on your problem https://youtu.be/AipHig2dkQE ... ;)

Comment: Wow fantastic breakdown! I think the idea of making each filter toggle-able, rather than just the option to edit or delete is a great idea and we will definitely be implementing something along these lines — thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get it right but I would recommend having more of a visual hint that the filters build up on each other and have like an accumulated value of what your output will be.

[image]

In eCommerce you have for example a number of potential results which updates if you add one.

[image]

Comment: This is interesting... I think my concern here would be that after 4/5 filters have been applied, you're shifting things so far to the right that the screen width becomes a limitation in how much you can display, and how good it can look